# file upload POST with php not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

First I make the db...

```
CREATE TABLE `contents`.`tbl_uploads` (
`id` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`file` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
`type` VARCHAR( 10 ) NOT NULL ,
`size` INT NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

I connect to the db using PDO...

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=content", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
     echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Then when the POST request is made I attempt the following...

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 
    $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $folder="uploads/";

    move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$file);
    $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_uploads(file,type,size) VALUES(?,?,?)";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute(array('$file','$file_type','$file_size'));  
}
```

The only thing that seems to work properly is the `move_uploaded_file` because the txt file appears in my `uploads` folder. However an entry is made in my db but the entry looks like this...

```
id 1   file $file  type $file_type   size 0
```

Why aren't I able to make a proper entry?

Comment: remove the single quotes from `array('$file','$file_type','$file_size')`

Comment: @Derek that did it

Comment: Sweet, sometimes it just takes a fresh eye.

Answer (score -2):

Check your HTML form; it should have the following property:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: The issue was that OP was using *single* quotes to try and display a variable.